# Purchased property with incomplete Buildings Regulations UK

Tags: united-kingdom, property

About six ago we rented the first floor of a converted property. This property (and the flat below ours on the ground floor) was subsequently repossessed from the original landlord and we purchased it from the bank four years ago, with indemnity insurance to cover a number of missing pieces of paperwork. A different buyer purchased the ground floor.

Over time we have found a number of issues with the property which we have rectified as they have come up. Unfortunately we have also discovered that Buildings Regulations were not followed, or signed off, when the property was initially converted and we have been labouring to correct this since.

The most substantial failing in the regulations is that the property was not properly soundproofed. The bill to correct this will cost several thousand pounds, will be highly disruptive and even once complete is not guaranteed to pass subsequent tests.

How necessary is it to have these regulations signed off, given that it was not us who initially carried out the work, and what would happen if we knowingly sold/rented the property without this being done first?